# Allow traffic only by a specific ip

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I have two virtual machines created with Vagrant (provider Virtualbox):

A with ip: 100.10.10.10

B with ip: 172.28.128.42

C with ip: 192.28.128.41

They are running on the same host, i want that only A can talk with B, if i try to traceroute the traffic this is the response:

```sh
$ traceroute 172.28.128.42

 1  10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2)  0.066 ms  0.042 ms  0.083 ms
 2  172.28.128.42 (172.28.128.42)  0.218 ms  0.237 ms  0.216 ms
```

Therefore the traffic passes through 10.0.2.2 (localhost i guess,also work for C).
I try to achieve an isolation between A and B working with `iptables` like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 100.10.10.10 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.2.2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

But after that B become unreachable by C and A... and that's not the expected behavior.. how can i achieve that (only A and B can communicato, so only reachable by A)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a virtualization program like VirtualBox, maybe the problem is the configuration of the network.

By default, in most of the cases, the network is configured as NAT:
[image]

You can try to creat an Internal Network. In that way the VM are in ha separate LAN and do not use the Host for the comunications.

[image]

Images and info taken from [here](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/).

Comment: I'm using Vagrant with VirtualBox as provider. Vagrant need a NAT to work and provision the VMs, so every machine has a NAT that i can't delete. If i try to add an Internal_Network the communication pass by the NAT

Comment: In the official [documentation in Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/networking.html) say that you can create a Internal Network. Try if maybe it's works for you.

Comment: Yes, you can create an Internal Network but the NAT continue to exist because is necessary to Vagrant to manage the VM. Considering that the NAT continue to exist the traffic will pass through it and that's not what i want.

Comment: But as you can see in the VM1 in the second image, you have to add a second Network card in each VM and configure these second card as Internal Network (with news IPs and Mask and everything). Then you can use these interface 1 for the NAT communication with Vagrant and the interface 2 for internal communication between the VM.